# How list object in Google Cloud Storage is calculated?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Just a clarification, I know List objet to see all files in a bucket is a class A Operation in Google Cloud Storage, My question does it cost the same to list 10 files in a bucket or 1 Millions, how the cost is calculated exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `Object: list` call returns at most 1,000 objects. See the description of `maxResults` here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

You can request fewer, but you cannot request more than 1,000 in each RPC.  To get 1 million objects you need to make 1,000 calls, so it is about 1,000 times more expensive to get 1 million objects vs. getting 10 objects.

Comment: Thank you so much,  it was really confusing :)

Comment: There is no documented upper bound for the maxResults parameter.  Instead, "The recommended upper value for maxResults is 1000 objects in a single response."  I have routinely used this API call to list well over 1000 objects at a time.  The documentation may have changed since this answer.